# filter the data in grid view by using select query

Tags: sql, gridview, filter

I'm writing an asp.net using gridview .

I want the gridview to change by some kind of filter field

id , name , email 
if the user enter them it's filtered or bring all in database 
i write the query but the gridview always empty and didn't show up

```
SELECT id, name, email, isactive, password, xdatetime 
FROM bUser
WHERE ( (id = @id) AND (name LIKE '%'+@name+'%') AND (email LIKE '%'+@email+'%') )
```

help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM bUser 
WHERE (  (id+'' LIKE @id) and (name LIKE '%'+@name+'%') AND (email LIKE '%'+@email+'%') )
```

because @id is a string